# How do I output what classes are on the body tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know this is pretty basic, but how do I GET the class names that are on the body tag of my page and log them to the console? I have the following:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('OS 4') != -1) $("body").addClass('iOS4');
console.log($(body).attr(class).text());
```

Will this log out to the console whether or not my body tag has the 'ios4' class?

Comment: `document.body.className` will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
console.log($("body").attr("class"));
```

Yes, it will work regardless of whether your body has 'ios4' class.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up using.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('body').attr('class').split(' ')
```

then you should be able to loop through them

you can also use `.hasClass` to check.

http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

Comment: +1. You could also do `split(/\s+/)` which would take care of removing potential double spacing..

Comment: @Ben: Might want to throw a trim on there too, no?

Comment: Boy, how bad are we expecting this html to be? :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but console.log($("body").attr("class")); was what I was looking for. I always struggle with getting .hasClass to evaluate to true.

Answer (score 0):

The above post will definitely work. If you do not have access to jQuery however use className if you do not have it available to you.

```
console.log(document.body.className);
```

This should work and won't require jQuery.

Comment: I mis-read it at first. I thought he was trying to parse through a list of classnames that were comma separated. My mistake. I replaced it.

Comment: comma separated class names.. interesting :)

Comment: I had to parse through comma separated lists today at work in JS and I had that on my mind still. :)

Answer (score 0):

.
Well its simple, when not using JQuery, you can do it with:
***Also this version should work on all browsers(Includes: IE6+, FireFox:3+, Safari:1.3+, Opera:9+) :)***
.

```
//This will give a String containing all classes 
var classes = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].className;

//This will give a list(Array) of class Names
var classes = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].className.split(' ');
```

.

***You can replace "body" with any TAG of interest*** :)

**Note:** *document.getElementsByTagName("") returns an Array, as we know that there is only One BODY Tag in the page, hence we have taken the first element of the array, i.e.document.getElementsByTagName("")[0]*

Hope that helps
.
Regards Kushal

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for jQuery in any of this:

```
var classes = document.body.className;
var classList = classes.split(" ");
```